# Android MapView: Event for animateTo is finished?

Tags: android, android-mapview

Are there some kind events for `animateTo()` is finished in android's [MapView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)?

I don't mean manual scrolls, I mean `animateTo()`-calls from my code or `animateTo()`-calls causing by changing `myLocation` if `myLocation` is enabled?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is an `animateTo` that takes a Runnable parameter. You can use this in this manner:

```
    mapController.animateTo(geoPoint,
            new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // your code
                }
            });
```

Comment: thank you, also thought on this solution. And you answer helped me to decide for it :)